CSS: как динамически инвертировать цвет текста при наложении его на блок с тёмным фоном?
При наведении на цветной блок он плавно заползает под текст. Нужно, чтобы часть текста на фоне блока в этот момент меняла свой цвет на белый. Перепробовал все варианты mix-blend-mode - хотя бы немного меняют цвет текста hue, saturation и color, но это далеко не белый. Остальные либо не дают эффекта, либо скрывают текст под фоном.
Каким образом можно решить данную задачу? И можно ли вообще? Безо всяких костылей с дублированием текста, открытием/сокрытием и т.д.


main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
.main-text {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  /*mix-blend-mode: ;*/
}
.color-block {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2845AA;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    right: -90%;
    transition: .5s;
}
.color-block:hover {
    right: -40%;
}
<main>
  <div class="color-block"></div>
  <div class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.</div>
</main>




Ты про mix-blend-mode: difference;?

@ksa, я же написал, что перепробовал все варианты, в том числе и difference - не работает

Не на тот элемент ты их ставил. И вообще, нужны два оверлея: один для маски, а другой - для фона. Вот так (разметку не менял):


main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.main-text {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  z-index: 3;
}

.color-block {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0 0 0 auto;
  width: 10%;
  transition: .5s;
}

.color-block:hover {
  width: 60%;
}

.color-block::before, .color-block::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
}

.color-block::before {
  background: white;
  z-index: 4;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

.color-block::after {
  background: #D7BA55; /* станет #2845AA */
  z-index: 2;
}
<main>
  <div class="color-block"></div>
  <div class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.</div>
</main>




Сделал ещё вот такой кастыль с градиентом и анимацией. Выглядит конечно по-замудреннее, чем вариант с вычитанием, но со своей задачей справляется.


main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.main-text {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, black 100%, white 0%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  transition: background 0.5s ease;
  /*mix-blend-mode: ;*/
}

.color-block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2845AA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: -90%;
  transition: .5s;
}

.color-block:hover {
  right: -40%;
}

.color-block:hover+.main-text {
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 0.1s;
  animation-name: gradient-animation;
}

@keyframes gradient-animation {
  from {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 100%, white 0%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  10% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 95%, white 5%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  20% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 90%, white 10%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  30% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 85%, white 15%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  40% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 80%, white 20%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  50% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 75%, white 25%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  60% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 70%, white 30%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  70% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 65%, white 35%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  80% {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 60%, white 40%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
  to {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, black 57%, white 57%, white 100%);
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
  }
}
<main>
  <div class="color-block"></div>
  <div class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.</div>
</main>




Вот это уже интересно! Но есть косяк: при движении блока обратно текст сразу становится чёрным на фоне синего, и это сильно заметно. Можно ли как-то докрутить эту историю?

Можно разделить на две части:

черный текст на белом фоне
белый текст на синем



main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.main-text {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.white-block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  transition: .5s;
}

.color-block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2845AA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: -90%;
  transition: .5s;
  z-index: 1;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

.color-block:hover {
  right: -40%;
}

.color-block:hover+.white-block {
  width: 40%;
}
<main>
  <div class="color-block"></div>
  <div class="white-block"></div>
  <div class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.</div>
</main>




Почему в большинстве ответов (и твоём в том числе) шрифт получается какой-то паршивый? У меня вроде нормально получилось.

@Qwertiy, потому что это постобработка, когда цвет шрифта инвертирован. У меня микс применяется к тексту, а у тебя только к фону, вот и разница

Но при наложении у меня белый шрифт (точнее, часть, которая становится белой) тоже обработан миксом, но он не портится.

потому что у тебя в белый превращается - а он кажется меньше чем такой же черный :)

Вроде такой же?

@Qwertiy, я про визуальную часть

как на счёт театра теней? :3


main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.main-text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 .5em;
  max-width: 70%;
  line-height: 2;
  text-shadow: .5em 1em 0 white;
  mix-blend-mode: lighten;
}

.main-text::first-line {
  font: 30px bold;
}

#x:checked+.main-text {
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px gray;
  filter: drop-shadow(0 0 2px skyblue);
}

.color-block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2845AA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: -60%;
  transition: .5s;
}

.color-block:hover {
  right: 0;
}
<main>
  <div class="color-block"></div>
  <input type='checkbox' id='x' checked> <- убрать грязь
  <div class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.</div>
</main>




Можно использовать filter: invert(1) в сочетаний с mix-blend-mode: difference
P.S: если не добавить стиль filter: invert(1) для .color-block то цвет блока будет инверсирован а цвет текста который указан в background-color


main {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 30px 0;
  filter: invert(1); /* <- тут */
}

.main-text {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 70%;
  color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: difference; /* <- тут */
}

.color-block {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  filter: invert(1); /* <- тут, не обязательно */
  background-color: #2845AA;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  right: -90%;
  transition: 5s;
}

.color-block:hover {
  right: -40%;
}
<main>
  <div class="color-block"></div>
  <div class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos. Lorem ipsum dolor
    sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.</div>
</main>



Попытка № 2:
Используя background-image: linear-gradient и background-clip: text


.mix-text+.mix-text {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.mix-text {
  position: relative;
}

.mix-text:hover .box {
  width: var(--to);
}

.mix-text .text {
  color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 2s;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.mix-text:not(.reverse) .text {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white 50%, black 50%);
  background-position: calc(100% - var(--from)) 0;
}

.mix-text.reverse .text {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, white 50%, black 50%);
  background-position: calc(0% + var(--from)) 0;
}

.mix-text:not(.reverse):hover .text {
  background-position: calc(100% - var(--to)) 0;
}

.mix-text.reverse:hover .text {
  background-position: calc(0% + var(--to)) 0;
}

.mix-text .box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: var(--from);
  transition: all 2s;
  background: black;
  z-index: -1;
}

.mix-text:not(.reverse) .box {
  left: 0;
}

.mix-text.reverse .box {
  right: 0;
}
<div class="mix-text" style="--from: 40%; --to: 20%">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="mix-text" style="--from: 40%; --to: 60%">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="mix-text reverse" style="--from: 40%; --to: 20%">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<div class="mix-text reverse" style="--from: 40%; --to: 60%">
  <div class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.
  </div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>




всё бы хорошо, но цвет текста не белый

Действительно сложная задача. Если вам нужен именно синий фон, то вычитание здесь не поможет. Сделал вот такой вариант, конечно же нуждается в вашей доработке и будет работать только с чёрным цветом. Если пытаться делать с синим, то нужно вычесть из белого цвета желтый, но тогда и текст будет желтым.


main {
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
.main-text {
  position: relative;
  background:white;
  max-width: 70%;
  /*mix-blend-mode: ;*/
}

  .color-block {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    margin: auto;
    right: -100%;
transition: .5s;
    background: black;
    mix-blend-mode: difference;
  }
.color-block:hover{
    right: -40%;
    z-index:1000;
    background:white;
}
<main>
  <div class="main-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Doloribus tenetur saepe optio corrupti earum? Eligendi fugit nemo, quibusdam quas vero error qui obcaecati placeat suscipit provident? Consectetur, alias velit dignissimos.
  <div class="color-block"></div>
  </div>
</main>




Сорри, но это совсем не то, что надо, увы
